Making a topological space connected
Is there a notion of 'connectifying' a topological space similar to the idea of compactifying a topological space? The idea would be add in all the 'gaps' in the space.
Specifically, for $(X,\tau_X)$ a (disconnected) topological space, is there a reasonable topological space $(Y, \tau_Y)$ such that $X$ is homeomoprhic to a dense subset of $Y$?
I can think of an easy way of doing this by simply considering the space $X^*=X\cup \{x^*\}$ (for $x^*\notin X$) and defining $\tau_{X^*} = \tau\cup \{X^*\}$. This space is connected but destroys much of structure of $(X,\tau)$ and can never be Hausdorff.

Yes, there is an extensive literature about this. One of the basic papers is this by Watson and Wilson

@Ulli: You should write it as an actual answer (which it is unlike one posted and one deleted answers).

You can also consider the cone of a topological space X, denoted CX. This is the quotient space$X\times I / X\times \{1\}.$ This is a contractible space and if you take X to be disconnected this will create a path-connected space. (Since you are 'crushing/identifying' all of $X\times\{1\}$ to a point).

This would be path connected regardless of whether X is connected or not I believe.

But $X$ does not embed as a dense subset, as OP requested.
